# How to create heat map / Pandas Dataframe from data generated in nested loop?

Tags: python, pandas

Hey I want to create heat map (or Pandas Dataframe) from data generated in nested loop like in the example below:

```
for i in range (1,5):
    a = i + 2
    for n in range(1,5):
        c = n - 1
```

So my desired output is having on one axis `i` and on another `b` and as a values intersection of both - lets say `a+c`:

```
                   i 
           1   2   3   4   5
      1   (3) (4)
      2   (4)
  n   3   (5) 
      4
      5
```

number in parenthesis are results of `a+c`.
I think I should create a lists and appending them with results of those calculations but I don't know specifically how to do it.
Any advice will be helpful!

---

PS. This is simplified case, in my case this have to be nested loop - I want to check how changes in two features affecting predictions

Comment: Why burden yourself with pandas?  I don't see what it adds.  This kind of thing would be absolutely trivial by starting a numpy array filled with zeros.  After you populate the matrix, then you can convert to a dataframe if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this in order to show the code example.  I don't think this is a full answer to your problem, but it is the right direction.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((5,5), dtype=np.int32)

for i in range(5):
    for n in range(5):
        data[n,i] = (i+1+2) + (n+1-1)

print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you it was good idea to use Numpy instead of Pandas. With what you showed I managed to create what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding where you are using c, but this seems to be doing what you are looking for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3,4,5])

for i in range(1,6):
    df.loc[len(df.index)] = list(a+(i+1))

df.index += 1
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
1   3   4   5   6   7
2   4   5   6   7   8
3   5   6   7   8   9
4   6   7   8   9   10
5   7   8   9   10  11
```

Comment: Thats correct, thanks. I tried simplify more complex issue I guess not in the best way.